# Replace string in one part pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
print(df["date"].str.replace("2016","16"))
```

The code above works fine. What I really want to do is to make this replacement in just a small part of the data-frame. Something like:

```
df.loc[2:4,["date"]].str.replace("2016","16")
```

However here I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: Try removing the brackets from around "date".  Passing a single column label as a list in .loc forces a dataframe to return.  If you just pass a single label as a scalar you will return a pd.Series and the .str accessor will work.

Comment: Thank you. Doing a for loop can achieve the same thing as well.

Answer (score 2):

What about `df['date'].loc[2:4].str.replace('2016', 16')`?

By selecting `['date']` first you know you are dealing with a series which does have a string attribute.

Comment: Your solution works, I guess df.loc[2:4,"date"].str.replace("2016","16") is the same.